# Мерцание при анимации в canvas

Tags: анимация, canvas, html5

Здравствуйте.
Я делаю карусель изображений в canvas. Приведу только те участки кода, которые имеют непосредственное отношение к отрисовке, убрав лишнего для повышения читабельности.
На действие пользователя происходит вызов метода

```
rotateCarouselToLeft: function ()
    {
        currentCentralImagePositionX = currentCentralImagePositionX + 10;
            Carousel.drawImagesDisplayed();
            setTimeout(Carousel.rotateCarouselToLeft, 10);

    }
```

В методе drawImagesDisplayed высчитываются координаты углов изображений, т.к. это не строгие прямоугольники, а только по мере движения от края к центру канваса превращаются из трапеций в прямоугольники. Из метода drawImagesDisplayed вызывается уже непосредственно отрисовывающий метод

```
showImage: function (imageId, positionX, positionY, leftCornersOffsetY, rightCornersOffsetY)
    {
        var endPositionX = positionX + this.images.imageDisplayedWidth;

        if (positionX > Carousel.canvas.width && endPositionX > Carousel.canvas.width)
            return;

        if (positionX < 0)
            positionX = 0;

        if (endPositionX > Carousel.canvas.width)
            endPositionX = Carousel.canvas.width - 1;

        var imageWidth = endPositionX - positionX;

        Carousel.canvas.context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

        this.canvas.context.beginPath();
        this.canvas.context.moveTo(positionX, positionY - leftCornersOffsetY);

        //top horizontal line
        this.canvas.context.lineTo(endPositionX, positionY - rightCornersOffsetY);

        //right vertical line
        this.canvas.context.lineTo(endPositionX, positionY + this.images.imageDisplayedHeight + rightCornersOffsetY);

        //lower horizontal line
        this.canvas.context.lineTo(positionX, positionY + this.images.imageDisplayedHeight + leftCornersOffsetY);

        this.canvas.context.closePath();
        this.canvas.context.lineWidth = 4;
        this.canvas.context.strokeStyle = "grey";
        this.canvas.context.stroke();
        this.canvas.context.fill();

        var imageOffsetY = leftCornersOffsetY;
        if (rightCornersOffsetY > leftCornersOffsetY)
            imageOffsetY = rightCornersOffsetY;

        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function ()
        {
            Carousel.canvas.context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
            Carousel.canvas.context.drawImage(image,
                                positionX, positionY - imageOffsetY,
                                imageWidth, Carousel.images.imageDisplayedHeight + imageOffsetY * 2
                                );
        }
        image.src = this.images.imagesDirectory + this.images.imageNames[imageId];
    }
```

И вот собственно вопрос, который наверно уже понятен из заголовка. Во время движения этих изображений в среднем экран мерцает от одного до трех раз, что весьма заметно и портит очень сильно товарный вид. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать? Всем большое спасибо.

Comment: Так может Вы не будете перезагружать image каждый раз при вызове showimage? Я так понял, она у Вас вызывается как минимум раз в 10мс. Может попытаться кэшировать их, т.е. запоминать сам объект image где-нибудь выше этой функции? Идея навеяна отсюда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522341/how-to-redraw-canvas-every-250ms-without-flickering-between-each-redraw .

Comment: Оу, позор мне. Я итак собирался делать кэширование, но как-то не подумал, что уже совсем-совсем пора это сделать:).
Спасибо, решит это проблему или нет я узнаю после того, как попробую, но спасибо за толковый совет.

Comment: @hdimon, пожалуйста:) Ну держите в курсе. Сам ни разу не сталкивался с этим. Будем хоть знать как решить подобную проблему.

Comment: Да, обязательно! Как попробую, сразу здесь напишу. Может и вопрос нужно будет закрывать после этого:).

Answer (score 1):

Как очень разумно подсказал [@Dobby007](/users/1634/dobby007), стоило действительно всего лишь сделать кэширование. Необязательно делать предварительную загрузку изображения (хотя так работает лучше, понятно дело), достаточно просто загрузить изображение лишь один раз за анимацию, а не загружать заново при каждом сдвиге на несколько пикселей.